# warn: MOVNTDQ: Ignoring non-temporal hint, modeling as cacheable!, While simulating x86 with spec2006 benchamrks I am getting stuck in warn message

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, gem5

> warn: MOVNTDQ: Ignoring non-temporal hint, modeling as cacheable!, in x86 gem5.

What needs to be done in order to simulate the benchmarks without this message?

I have tried changing the memory size and also increased the stack size but nothing works

Comment: Those are stores that bypass cache like the WC mem type (and evict if already cached).  They're used for large array that won't be re-read soon, to avoid polluting cache with that data which couldn't benefit from caching anyway.  I don't know GEM5, but tuning sizes of things isn't going to make any difference; if it supported them it would do so with any memory size.  IDK if there are any boolean config options that might enable support, but I'd have guessed that they'd be enabled by default if they existed, to match how real x86 CPUs follow the NT hint even on WB memory regions.

Comment: It looks like gem5 simply [doesn't support simulating `movntdq` yet](https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/e8bc4fc137a5a7e82b601432271a027b652ae69b/src/arch/x86/isa/insts/simd128/integer/data_transfer/move_non_temporal.py#L38).